# Informatica Flat File import wizard not detecting all columns

Tags: file, informatica, flat

I have a file I need to import using the flat file wizard. For some reason - it only detects 153 columns out of 218. How can I get the wizard to detect all of the columns? There are not multiple consecutive delimiters, or any delimiters other than commas. It is a CSV file.

Comment: Please check the file properly. Make sure there are 217 commas in each line. You can open it excel to check if all 218 columns are present.

Comment: All of the commas are there...I checked in Notepad++. There is nothing unusual that I can see about the column that follows the last one detected by the wizard; the file has spacing issues but no missing delimiters, multiple consecutive delimiters, etc.

Comment: Can you provide some more information, such as *which* 153 columns make it through, or a sample record, or if any errors are returned on import?